# Preserving formula of a column when adding new rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet which looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

The C column is simply the product of column A and B. This formula is replicated in the entirely of column C, from row 2 to 1000.

However, if I add a new row between two existing rows, the formula is no longer there for that specific row. Looking around for solutions, I came across ArrayFormula. I changed my formula to the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(A2="",B2=""),"",PRODUCT(A2:A, B2:B)))
```

However, this messed up the result. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ARRAYFORMULA` does not understand `OR` so you need to convert it into 0/1 logic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((A2:A="")+(B2:B="")), , A2:A*B2:B))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: delete C3 and C4

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Please see this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t_MWoC-WoSNeU5poDbNgfW1509JEHzcDdPXFg6CNaUA/edit?usp=sharing